# Как устранить нежелательную прокрутку страницы, при скроллинге открытого меню сайта на iphone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Приветствую вас комрады! Помогите разобраться с очень странной проблемой прокрутки сайта.

Есть сайт, а у сайта есть менюшка, которая появляется когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку вызова меню. Открыв меню и начав листать список находящийся в этом самом меню, начинает прокручиваться сайт, но это только на ios, на android такого к счастью нет... Помогите разобраться с данной проблемой.

[Пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=IihXWK7nEN8)

Comment: Код в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: Если быть более точным, то для body ставь overflow: hidden при открытии формы.

Comment: Для body уже пробовал ставить overflow: hidden и это не помогло... А если быть точнее это не работает только на iphone, а на android всё прекрасно работает. Отлично исправляет ситуацию position: fixed ноооооо когда открываешь менюшку, сайт сразу прокручивается вверх.

Answer (score 0):

Комрады! Всё я разобрался с этой проблемой, можно не отправлять ответы с решением.=) 
**Для тех кто столкнулся с этой же проблемой и зашёл сюда, что бы найти решение, я пишу свой вариант того, как убрать нежелательный скролл модального окна.** 


CSS

body{position:fixed};

JS

document.getElementById('#ButtonMenu').onclick = function() {

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.marginTop = "-" + scrollY + 'px';

}

Cыровато, но этого вам хватит.